# jqGrid delRowData removes and adds the row back it on reload

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid which is client-side sorting with client-side JSON data. But the problem is when I delete a row (it gets deleted from the grid, which is good) and then if I reload the grid to update the paging data the deleted row comes back (which is Bad)  I have a jqGrid which is client-side sorting with client-side JSON data. But the problem is when I delete a row (it gets deleted from the grid, which is good) and then if I reload the grid to update the paging data the deleted row comes back (which is Bad)

Below is the link to replicate it in jsfiddle. For illustration clicking  a row would delete the row.

http://jsfiddle.net/wqouh57L/56/

```
 onSelectRow: function (id) 
 {
    $("#grid").delRowData(id);
    $("#grid").trigger('reloadGrid');

   }
```

Comment: It's very important to write in the text of every question which version of jqGrid and from which fork you use. Many problems exist because of wrong usage of some methods. Some other exist because of bugs in jqGrid. In both cases it's very important to be able *to reproduce* the reported problem. Thus it's better to create the demo. You can use JSFiddle for example.

Comment: @Oleg I edited the question to added a Demo in jsfiddle. The sorting is also not working well Ex. Sort by Status and see what happens.

Comment: Is the demo really corresponds your real code? If I select the row I see that the row will be successful deleted. You wrote about adding the rows after reload, but one can see that the grid contains less and less rows. By the way you use `<table id="pgrgrid"></table>` for the pager, which is wrong (it should be `<div>` of cause). The demo contains many syntax error, like usage of the same property more as once. http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/wqouh57L/58/ contains modified code which have `viewrecords: true` to simplify examining the results.

Comment: @Oleg no the demo is a quick and dirty stuff I created.My real code is very hard to be in jsfiddle demo because I create the grid options in a C# code and use newtonsoft.json to serialize it and use that to create the grid in js.                                        I just cleaned up my code and removed the key:true from the FileId which is a GUID and let jqGrid use its own autoincremented Id, Everything works. Thanks for your time and efforts as usual.